# Android seekbar with marks at discrete progress points

Tags: android, seekbar

I want to have a seekbar(like int the link: [YUI Library Examples](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/slider/slider-ticks.html)) with marks at discrete progress points, but the progress interval is not static. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I am also interested in this question. I **think** that you will have to create one yourself.

Comment: Did you create a custom one? Want to share your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can code up a custom `View` that draws the vertical lines at whatever points you want.

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

You'll just need to override `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` to draw your lines. You can use proportions of the width of the view as your markers. Each vertical line would be at the point

> lineNumber * (viewWidth) / numLines
>
> from lineNumber = 0 to lineNumber = numLines-1

Your progress would be drawn in a similar manner, but yeah.. you've gotta do this yourself.