# How to set drawable points and thumb on a seekbar?

Tags: android, xml, android-canvas, android-paint

I have no idea how I must make drawable points and thumb. I've read a lot of information about Canvas drawing, Paint, etc. But it didn't help.
I need to make Seekbar like seekbar in the pictures but with drawable points and drawable thumb. I can't use shapes because I need only drawable.

[image: snapshot]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7Ewr.png)

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648477/android-seekbar-with-marks-at-discrete-progress-points

Comment: Thanks!!) But I need to use drawable for points(tick marks) and for a thumb...I can't use shapes for it....i must do something like this:  https://slack-imgs.com/?c=1&url=https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Flawloretienne%2FDiscreteSlider%2Fmaster%2Fimages%2FDiscreteSlider_Screenshot4.png